# Menu 3 levels only horizontal HTML/CSS/JavaScript + pushcontent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a 3 levels ul li menu that take 100% width of the container but children ul goes under the parent level.

[This is a screen what i'm trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YKZ9.png)

```css
#fakeheader,
#fakecontent{
  width:100%
   height:50px;
  background:red;
  position:relative
  }
#nav {position: relative;}
#nav li {
    list-style:none;
    float: left;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:hover {
 background-color:red;
 color:#FFF;
 opacity:1;
}

/* Targeting the first level menu */
#nav {  
   
    min-width:850px;
    background:#fff;
    opacity:0.5;
    display: block;
    height: 34px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}
#nav > li > a {
}

/* Targeting the second level menu */
#nav li ul {
    color: #333;
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    width:850px;
}
#nav li ul li {
    display: inline;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    line-height: 34px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 8px 0 10px;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover {
    background-color:red;
    color:#FFF;
    opacity:1;
}

/* Third level menu */
#nav li ul li ul{
    top: 0;
}
ul.child {
background-color:#FFF;  
}
/* A class of current will be added via jQuery */
#nav li.current > a {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    float:left;
}
/* CSS fallback */
#nav li:hover > ul.child {
    left:0;
    top:34px;
    display:inline;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:left;
}
#nav li:hover > ul.grandchild  {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="fakeheader">Test
</div>

<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="#">Speakers</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="#">10 watt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">20 watt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">30 watt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Speakers</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="#">10 watt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">20 watt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">30 watt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="#">Speakers</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="#">10 watt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">20 watt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">30 watt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Speakers</a>
                <ul class="child">
                    <li><a href="#">10 watt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">20 watt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">30 watt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
   
</ul>

<div id="fakecontent">
test
</div>
```

Also is it possible then to push the content that will be under the menu?

Thanks in advance for any help and sorry for my bad english :P

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add some styles:

```
#main-menu ul {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
#main-menu > ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
#main-menu > ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I updated my code in a jsfiddle i manage to make the three level work but now i block on pushing the content when the second or third level are show.  https://jsfiddle.net/v8xLmbrt/2/ Do you have an idea?

Comment: second and third level are positioned absolute, so their container wouldn't resize and push content down, I think you need some piece of jquery code to achieve this